# JoinTable not generated with @OrderColumn annotation

Tags: hibernate

I think that must work, but seems not. I have an entity, let's call it 'team' that has a list of members where the order is important.

```
@Table(name = "teams")
public class Team {
    ...

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "members_of_team")
    @OrderColumn(name = "index")
    private List<User> members;
}
```

What I expect for this, is if I set

```
spring.datasource.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

The table `members_of_team` must be generated. But all tables except this one are generated. No error is shown, but I also have a script to populate the database, and when tries to insert data on this table, obviously fails.

The point is, that if I remove `@OrderColumn` annotation, the table is generated correctly, and the database script is loaded correctly, but probably the order is not assured.

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26054568/hibernate-manytomany-with-an-order-in-jointable/26062293) seems that I am not doing something strange. But for some reasons, seems not working. I am interested in preserving the order of the member list.

The versions I am using are Hibernate 5.4.32.Final, Spring Boot 2.5.5 and MySQL Connector 5.1.49 (with a MySQL 5.7 server).

How can I create the Join Table with order?

Comment: please provide all the relevant code `Team.class` and `User.class` and the database script that you mention that is loaded

Comment: To be honest, I think that all relevant code is already there. User ha no bidirectional relation with teams and only a set of columns not linked to it. And the script if for populating the data, nothing related to the database creation itself. Then must not be related to the generation of the table. Only a few `INSERT INTO members_of_team (team_id, member_id) VALUES (1, 20),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found the issue. The problem is that I am probably not using the best noun on the name of the column in `@OrderColumn(name = "index")`. Using `index` is not a good idea and causes the described issue of the question. If I change it to `column_index` or something else, is working fine and all data is populated correctly.